# Getting Tx is not a constructor when executing this program

Tags: web3js, javascript

Here is my code. I am trying to send ether from one account to another.

```
var Tx     = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/1ac73a4112ab456cb5bdd3ac33e4fe82')

const account1 = '<Account 1>'
const account2 = '<Account 2>'

const k1 = Buffer.from('<Private key 1>','hex')
const k2 = Buffer.from('<Private key 2>','hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1,(err,txCount)=>{
    //building a transaction
    const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to:       account2,
    value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
  }

  // Sign the transaction
  const tx = new Tx(txObject)
  tx.sign(k1)

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  // Broadcast the transaction
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
    console.log('txHash:', txHash)
  })
})
```

The error thrown is as follows:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Tx is not a constructor
>       at GetTransactionCountMethod.web3.eth.getTransactionCount (C:\Users\Atul\Web3_code\send_transaction.js:22:14)
>       at GetTransactionCountMethod._callee$ (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:126:22)
>       at tryCatch (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97:21)
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
>       at _next (C:\Users\Atul\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:10632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:10632) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I'm extremely new to this. Pls help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the new version you should

change

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
```

to

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
```

Comment: You're welcome! Our pleasure! Please accept the answer then other people can know when they face the same issue :)

Comment: You're a hero @HaĐANG, but do you have where this change is documented? This wasted a couple hours of my time before finding this question. Google is now the worst for searching because of their quest for propaganda, I had to go 15 pages deep on Bing. This answer should be #1.

Comment: Thank you for nice words. I don’t have the document. Just look into the latest code to understand:)